# how to connect MySQL hosted in my computer to an Android app using Kotlin

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin

Can I connect an Android app to MySQL database in my computer? Just tell me the way or a library name and let me google it to learn about.

Comment: I do a fast search and i found this: [Android Sample](https://gist.github.com/cofearabi/5039135) and [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

Comment: that will help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL connector for java works for Kotlin as well. You can download it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads

And then you can kotlint like that:

```
val connectionProps = Properties()
connectionProps.put("user", username)
connectionProps.put("password", password)

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(“url”, connectionProps)
} catch (ex: SQLException) {
    // handle any errors
    ex.printStackTrace()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    // handle any errors
    ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: thank you i will learn jdbc i need to know more about that how create tables and how to insert and view .......